# Running NPM scripts sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cmd

Let's say I have

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-build": "echo \"Welcome\" && exit 1",
    "build_logic": "start cmd.exe @cmd /k \"yo esri-appbuilder-js:widget && exit 1\"",
    "post_build":  "start C:\\WebAppBuilderForArcGIS\\startupShortcut",
    "exit" : "start cmd.exe @cmd /k \"echo \"goodbye\" && exit 1\""
  },
```

What NPM command can I run to let all of these scripts launch sequentially. When I use pre/post fixing they launch sequentially but they don't wait for the parent script to finish before executing. I am assuming the only solution is like: [How do I get Gulp tasks to fire sequentially when firing shell commands in an async.series helper function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25371192/3174123) ? I know this can be done with Gulp but I would like to stick with NPM for now to explore its capabilities. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Updated answer at the bottom

Comment: According the documentation of `Start` command, you should be able to use `/wait` parameter (Start application and wait for it to terminate)

Answer (score 524, accepted):

Invoke these scripts via npm run and chain them with double ampersand **`&&`**:

```
npm run pre-build && npm run build_logic && npm run post_build && npm run exit
```

Explanation:

- Use **`&&`** (double ampersand) for sequential execution.
- Use **`&`** (single ampersand) for parallel execution.

Comment: This works the best because it executes in order, being that each command doesn't execute until the previos is finished, as requested in the OP. Thanks

Comment: `&&` are evaluated by the shell and don't work on Windows.

Comment: Lets say that I have two scripts within my app. One launch a live server (script1), and another one a dyson server (script2). How I can create a script that triggers those two previous scripts? thanks :)

Comment: @BernhardDöbler just add another npm command containing the above command - you don't have to run (and remember) this whole string from windows CLI.

Comment: @RafeGoldberg The && operator has the same execution behavior in both windows and *nix environments, i.e. sequential execution..Unless there's something we're all missing?

Comment: @Rice oy vey; was being dumb and mixing up my single and double-ampersand operators. Per the `npm-run-all` docs: “we sometimes use `&` to run multiple command in parallel, but Windows' `cmd.exe`... does not support [this operator].” So it'd appear you were right — at least from my brief research the `&&` operator seems perfectly cross-platform compatible.

Comment: How can we chain ```npm i``` with something? I tried and it failed as it considers && as a package.

Comment: @Rishinder just list all the packages you want to install separated by a **whitespace**: `npm i package1 package2 package3`

Comment: @Mobiletainment, that's not what I was trying to achieve. I wanted to execute other non installation scripts after ```npm i``` but it doesn't let me chain those. I've figured out a workaround but not very satisfied with it.

Comment: @VPaul Shouldn't you perhaps use `postinstall` script for that?

Comment: I have read that the only difference between `&` and `&&` is that `&&` performs error checking and will not run commands to the right, if the commands on the left don't return expected result. [MS:KB Archive](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/279253)

Comment: On Windows 10 the `&&` works for me. I have a ghost blog which my next js app connects to it. So, I use this command in my `package.json` file to run both the blog and the next js sequentially:
`"scripts": { "all": "cd my-blog-folder && ghost start && cd.. && next dev", ... }`. Then I run this command to execute that: `npm run-script all`

Comment: Coming here from an issue I face - "killall node && next dev" why doesn't this run sequentially? (> killall node && next dev....Terminated)

Comment: @Qwerty - This is for sure true on Windows, the single `&` may be context sensitive on unix and do other things .

Comment: as was mentioned  && will not work in Windows shell ```&& are evaluated by the shell and don't work on Windows```, however it will work in git bash shell (automatically installed by git) or if you need it in regular cmd, than simple install of https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow utils will do the thing

Comment: && works for me on windows shell. However single & does not. Concurrently or an inline node script is the correct way to run commands in parallel.

Comment: Calling out to another script worked for me instead of `&` (ignore exit code) `"my-script": "npm run some-command-with-non-0-exit-code && do-something-else"`

Comment: This answer frightens me. `&&` does run commands sequentially, if and only if the first command is successful (usually what you want). `&` does NOT run commands in parallel, though it may seem that way: The first command runs in the background, so its output might get lost and its success/failure certainly does. The entire process ends when the second command exits, meaning the first command might get killed off before it completes. @Or A's answer below is a viable option for sequential processing. `concurrently` is also a great option for running in parallel.

Answer (score 56):

Following @Mobiletainment's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172660/2139929), you can also use [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) to make the command much shorter and much more readable. In your case:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "run-s pre-build build_logic post_build exit"
}
```

`run-s` is a shortcut `npm-run-all` provides, that runs all the given npm-scripts sequentially, hence the `-s` (`run-s` is a shorter version of `npm-run-all -s`).

Comment: While this seems like an elegant solution at first, checking out the dependency tree of `npm-run-all` reveals that it has 69 dependencies (not counting dev deps!), see e.g. https://npm.broofa.com/?q=npm-run-all . No thanks, I dont want to be a victim of some kind of sideload attack or a farce like the `left-pad` issue.

Comment: Do I see this correctly, that `run-s` is really just replacing `npm run pre-build && npm run build_logic && npm run post_build && npm run exit`?

why would I introduce another dependency, that confuses every developer, who knows the `&&` command? In my case I am working on project that uses `run-s` (introduced by another dev) and it confuses me rather than helping me!

Can I remove run-s securely or am I missing a difference here?

Comment: I think that, if you have a lot of scripts to run, and you are using Package.json as a Task Runner (like **Grunt** or **Gulp**) then **npm-run-all** may be a valid tool. However, if you want to run only two scripts like `build` and `clean` (for example) then I prefer to use the `&&` syntax.

Answer (score 44):

You can prefix your scripts `pre` and `post` so they will execute automatically:

```
"scripts": {
  "prebuild": "echo \"Welcome\" && exit 1",
  "build": "start cmd.exe @cmd /k \"yo esri-appbuilder-js:widget && exit 1\"",
  "postbuild":  "start C:\\WebAppBuilderForArcGIS\\startupShortcut",
  "exit" : "start cmd.exe @cmd /k \"echo \"goodbye\" && exit 1\""
}
```

then run `npm run build`

Comment: this doesn't work, as indicated in the question: "When I use pre/post fixing they launch sequentially but they don't wait for the parent script to finish before executing."

Answer (score 24):

You could just string them into another script. `"start": "pre-build && build_logic && post_build && exit"`

Comment: I would require them to wait for each other to finish, these will fire off sequentially but won't wait.

Comment: I don't think this is a node / npm problem. The `start` command you are executing in windows technically *is* finished. Use the `/wait` flag with `start` to force the `start` application to remain open until the internal method is also finished.

Comment: To test this -- run `start notepad` from a command prompt, then take a look at the original command prompt. You should be able to type in another command. Then run `start /wait notepad`. The `start` command should continue to "run" while your notepad window is open (take a look at the command prompt again). Then once you close notepad, `start` will be finished.

Comment: The \wait solution does not work for commands appended via double ampersand or pre/post fixed npm commands.

Comment: This doesn't work on windows.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [**npm-run-all**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) to combine multiple commands in a lot of different ways

For example, if you had the following scripts in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "lint":  "eslint src",
    "build": "babel src -o lib"
}
```

You could run them all sequentially like this:

```sh
$ npm-run-all clean lint build
```

See this question for [how to run multiple npm commands in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585721/1366033)

Comment: This is the way to go.  npm-run-all is the best.  And will produce a package.json that is cross-platform.

Answer (score 6):

you can try:

```
"scripts": {
  "clean-dist": "rm -f ./dist/*.js && rm -f ./dist/*.map",
  "build": "npm run clean-dist && parcel build ./packages/index.html"
},
```

Answer (score 5):

There are several options that are better than the accepted answer:

- `&&` - runs commands sequentially, as long as each is successful: `command && command && command`; supported in *most* shells (early versions of Powershell did not support this) (thanks @Mobiletainment)
- `;` - runs commands sequentially, ignoring success/failure; supported in most, if not all, shells
- the `npm-run-all` package - can run multiple commands either in sequence or in parallel; see [the documentation](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/blob/master/docs/npm-run-all.md) for usage (thanks @Or A.)
- the `concurrently` package - runs multiple commands in parallel (included because this is a popular Google result); see [the documentation](https://github.com/open-cli-tools/concurrently#readme) for usage

Answer (score 2):

#### Sequential & Parallel Mix Example

In case you need a mix, here's what I did to ensure command_1 runs and completes first, while command_2a and command_2b can run in parallel.

```json
    "dev": "yarn command_1 && (yarn command_2a & yarn command_2b)"
```

Practical Example:

```json
    "dev": "yarn buildPackage && (yarn watchPackageSource & yarn watchExamplePage)"
```

Comment: OS specific, doesn't work on windows

Comment: That is not necessarily true and depends on your windows version and the shell that you use. Check the comments here (and maybe best use a unix shell): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172660/5037146

Comment: the point of npm is to be cross-shell/platform. otherwise you should stick with .sh, .bat, .makefile,  cmake, sln, ... - Concurrently is an npm option. && is cross platform (seems to work even in powershell, even though running directly fails). & is not

Answer (score 2):

For all those who read this question in 2023, nowadays, Windows WSL allows you to run the Linux commands concatenation style '&' without installing additional dependencies.

We can bypass the command to WSL from PowerShell/cmd like that

`wsl npm run build & npm start`

It will depend slightly on what kind of instructions you want to run in such as .bat, .sh ...

[image]