# How to make a terminal command wait for another to be finished?

Tags: node.js, terminal, package.json

I have this command in my package.jason:

```
"chrome": "node --max_old_space_size=10000 build/dev-server.js --arg testus | node --harmony test/e2e/puppeteer/index.js",
```

I want to build my app before using my automated testing tool.

But right now both commands start at the same time.

How to do the second one waits the first one to be finished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running NPM scripts sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172536/running-npm-scripts-sequentially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run something in sequence in linux command line you use `&&`

```
"chrome": "node --max_old_space_size=10000 build/dev-server.js --arg testus && node --harmony test/e2e/puppeteer/index.js",
```

Comment: Oh, it almost worked. But now the server is listening to port 8080 and it's stuck there without running the command after `&&` ...

Comment: An other way to do it is to put the server in background  with `&` and then run the second after `;`

Sort of `first_command & ; second_command`

The `;` same as `&&` for sequence

Answer (score 1):

what about a proper bash script like:

```
node --max_old_space_size=10000 build/dev-server.js --arg testus 
while [ ! $(http://example.org 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2) -eq 200 ]; do
  echo "Waiting for server to start!"
  sleep 2
done
echo "Server started !!!! "
node --harmony test/e2e/puppeteer/index.js"
```