# How can I run multiple npm scripts at the same time?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

In my `package.json`, I defined two scripts. How do I run them at the same time?

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack -wd",
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run multiple npm scripts in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30950032/how-can-i-run-multiple-npm-scripts-in-parallel)

Answer (score 14):

Invoke scripts via npm run with & for parallel execution or with && for sequential execution:

```
npm run server & npm run webpack
```

Explanation:

```
Use &&  for sequential execution.
Use &  for parallel execution.
```

Comment: It doesn't seems to work with express. I have this `node serverNew.js & ng serve ` and all I get is  `app running on port 5000` without continuing to the `ng serve` command

Comment: A unix-only solution is unfortunately not a solution. Node and npm are cross-platform, solutions really should be, too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Not to mention that explanation and lack of ability for it to run B if A end with an error code. And the fact many users won't know how to regain control of the process after detaching with `&`, other than rebooting.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [**npm-run-all**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all)* to combine multiple commands in a lot of different ways
<sup>***WARNING: last updated 2018**</sup>

For example, if you had the following scripts in your `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
    "lint":  "eslint src",
    "build": "babel src -o lib"
}
```

You could run them in parallel like this:

```bash
$ npm-run-all --parallel lint build
```

See this question for [how to run multiple npm commands sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585697/1366033)

Comment: Note that `npm-run-all` was abandoned in 2018, so at this point it's safe to assume it might have vulnerabilities that are never going to get patched.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, ooh - good point.  Adding note

Answer (score 3):

```
"scripts": {
    "sw": "webpack-dev-server & webpack -wd"
},
```

then

```
npm run sw
```

Answer (score 3):

As of now the syntax seems to have changed a little bit you need to pass & within quotes .

Below is the command that I ran for my demo scripts.

for sequential execution :

```
npm run temp '&&' npm run temp1
```

for parallel execution

```
npm run temp '&' npm run temp1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a module like parallelshel.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallelshell

As it says npm official site:

> The biggest difference is that parallelshell is an npm module and GNU
>   parallel isn't. While they probably do similar things, albeit (GNU)
>   parallel being more advanced, parallelshell is an easier option to
>   work with when using npm (because it's an npm module).
>
> If you have GNU parallel installed on all the machines you project
>   will be on, then by all means use it! :)

-

> How is this different than:
>
> `$ cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3`
>
> - Cross platform -- works on Unix or Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run multiple npm scripts.

Steps:

1. Run `npm i concurrently` to install concurrently.
2. Modified scripts in package.json by adding **all** (You may change to other name).

   "scripts": {
       "server": "webpack-dev-server",
       "webpack": "webpack -wd",
       "all": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run webpack\""
   },
3. Run `npm run all` to execute multiple npm scripts.
4. Confirm the output in console log.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `&` for parallel run script

```
"dev": "npm run start-watch & npm run wp-server"
```

[Reference link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-command-or-code-in-parallel-in-bash-shell-under-linux-or-unix/)