# Run two scripts from package.json

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

My package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon src $NODE_DEBUG_OPTION --exec babel-node",
    "build": "babel src -s -D -d dist",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  }
```

I have to run two commands:

```
npm run dev
```

And

```
npm run tsc:w
```

Is it possible to include the typescript watcher in the `dev`?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running NPM scripts sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172536/running-npm-scripts-sequentially)

Comment: You can use pre and post! They will run automatically before or after your script.

Comment: @Kokodoko Can you show how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pre` and `post` scripts that will run before and after your intended script.

This should run `tsc` on .ts files, and then `browserify` on the compiled .js files:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "tsc",
    "build": "browserify dev/main.js -o docs/js/main.js"
}
```

In terminal:

```
npm run build
```