# Run two scripts that don't end in package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I'm trying to start a [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) and start my React-App in the same script in package.json ...

But the problem is that none of the two scripts give me the prompt back so the second script is never launched ...

I've tried :

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "npm run start-db & npm start-react",
   "start-react": "react-scripts start && exit 1",
   "start-db": "json-server --watch src/bdd.json -p 3001 && exit 1"
}
```

with differents combinations of `&&` or `&`... With or without `exit 1` ( things that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172660/3636091) )

Comment: Open multiple terminals and run each in a separate terminal

Comment: Well ... That's what I'm doing for the moment ... Isn't it possible to merge this in package.json ?

Comment: I don't think so, since both of them are seperate servers. Both are on seperate port numbers right?

Comment: Yes ``react-scripts start`` serve on default port ( 3000 ) that's why I've specified ``-p 3001`` for the json-server command

Comment: these are two servers. you cannot run multiple instances of a server on one shell. This is because the server has to keep on running and provide data whenever queried upon. When you exit, there is no server to listen to the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a tool like [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm:start-db\" \"npm:start-react\"",
    "start-react": "react-scripts start",
    "start-db": "json-server --watch src/bdd.json -p 3001"
}
```

after installing it with `npm i --save-dev concurrently`.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass multiple commands like this

```
npm run start-db start-react
```

Comment: Still get stuck in the ``json-server --watch src/bdd.json -p 3001`` command and don't start react app

Comment: I'm not getting any error ... The script is just waitting to log user's interactions with the server like ``GET /people 304 15.296 ms``... So it doesn't give back hand ... So the second script isn't launched