# How to control VSCode compound launch sequence?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to control the order in which Visual Studio Code spawns the various projects when working with a compound configuration?  For example...

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Config API First",
      "configurations": [
        "E API - Config",
        "E API - Authentication"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From what I can find ([vscode-recipies/102](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/issues/102), etc.), VSCode handles them in parallel.  It looks like the only way to handle it is outside of VSCode, [for example, with a NPM script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172536/running-npm-scripts-sequentially), however, it feels impossible that Microsoft would not have accounted for this.