# How to run multiple npm scripts both on unix and windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to run multiple npm scripts **synchronous**.(one after another) For example here are my npm scripts.I have both bower and npm packages in my project.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "installnpm": "npm i",
    "installbower": "bower i",
    "rimraf":"rimraf dist"
    "lernabootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "start":"nodemon myApp.js"
  }
}
```

How can I run multiple scripts both on unix and windows without any error?
Scripts also includes npm and bower install commands like you see.Does it matter for this situation?

Comment: When you say `synchronously`, I assume by that you mean serially, as in one after another? That's generally what "synchronous" means when describing code. If so, I believe both *nix and windows support the `&&` operator between commands. e.g. `npm i && bower i && ...`

Comment: @David784 I haven't seen the syntax of && on Windows as a thing.  Is that something npm implements specifically or do you have a reference that that's viable?

Comment: @Joe, why don't you just [try it!!!?!?!?!](https://pastebin.com/0SNc2bRS)

Comment: @gman I don't have a windows system handy

Comment: I just tried it in my win10 VM, and it works great. Also [Here's a historical SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd) that gives some history. Here's the example I used: `dir && echo "hello world"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run commands synchronously by using `&&` in both Windows and Unix environments.

So ...

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "installnpm": "npm i",
    "installbower": "bower i",
    "rimraf":"rimraf dist"
    "lernabootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "start":"nodemon myApp.js",
    "all": "npm run installnpm && npm run installbower && npm run start"
  }
}
```

so then you could run `npm run all` to execute all those npm scripts synchronously

Here is a answer that answers it for [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8055390/1554860) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172660/1554860) is useful as well.