# How to chain multiple commands in npm package.json scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp

I am trying to create a script in my package.json file that will launch my nodemon app, then trigger a gulp sass watch

Currently, I can do this by running a `npm launch` which starts nodemon, then in a separate terminal window I can run `gulp watch` to trigger the sass watch from my gulp file.

I would like to create a single script command in package.json that will do both of these- is that possible?

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "launch": "nodemon app.js && gulp watch"
  },
```

gulpfile.js

```
const { src, dest, watch } = require("gulp");
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('node-sass'));

function generateCSS(cb) {
    src('./sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(dest('public/css'));
    cb();
}

function watchFiles(cb) {
    watch('sass/**/**.scss', generateCSS);
}

exports.css = generateCSS;
exports.watch = watchFiles;
```

edit: please see my answer below for what worked for me, inspired by the answer from @cmgchess

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172536/running-npm-scripts-sequentially

Comment: no snap, that worked! according to that SO post '&&' executes the commands sequentially, while '&' executes the commands in parallel. So perhaps because nodemon launch but does not end, it never gets around to executing `gulp watch` when using `&&`. @cmgchess if you want to submit this as an answer I'll gladly confirm and upvote

Comment: I think since you already found the Answer in the link it would be better if I do not repost. Anyway you are free to answer your own question with what worked for you

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `&&`

`package.json`

```
"build": "npm run base && npm run utilities:global && npm run utilities:unstyled && npm run utilities:styled && npm run components && npm run merge:unstyled && npm run merge:styled && npm run rtl && npm run prejss && npm run themes && npm run full",
```

Comment: well I had that thought too and actually line 3 in my scripts object in my original post currently has the && in it, however it is not kicking off the gulp watch, only the nodemon service

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) package and its `run-p` command to execute multiple scripts side-by side:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js",
    "watch": "gulp watch",
    "launch": "run-p start watch"
},
```

Then you can just do:

```
npm launch
```

Comment: @JKRishe I think this would certainly work but after reading @cmgchess comment above I wonder if using `&` is better suited for my use case, since my script is relatively simple. either way I'll keep this package under my cap, thank you- seems like it will be very useful for complex setups!

Comment: @kdub1312 I can't imagine there's any real problem with using `&`. I prefer the npm-run-all approach because it makes things cleaner - the scripts are defined individually and can be run individually, and modified if need be. Then the `launch` script very succinctly conveys that it's running those scripts in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

per @cmgchess answer in the comments, it turns out using a double ampersand runs the command sequentially. however, there is also the option to use a single ampersand, which will run them in parallel. In this case, this is what I needed:

```
"launch": "nodemon app.js & gulp watch"
```

edit: ok the first time I ran the launch it worked fine. however, subsequent launches crashed. I have it working again now over multiple launches, and what I had to do additionally is switch the order of the commands:

```
"launchreverse": "gulp watch & nodemon app.js"
```